# c# How to do automatic check when the table is inserted a new row

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, insert, insert-update

I have table messages and I linked it it with DataGridView and I want him to be updated automatically if new row is inserted in table by other pc, i can use refresh button with following code source :

```
datagridview1.update();
datagridview1.refresh();
```

or i can use thread with interval of 1000 ms , 
but i want more Instantaneous method like socket in network, any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your database is SQL Server. Then, you can use the [SQL Server Service Broker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx) (SSB), so that your datagrid updates automatically on DB changes.

You should take a look at [this project on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233770/AutoRefresh-Entity-Framework-data-using-SQL-Server). Using the ServiceBrokerUtility, it's easy to refresh your object set not only once, but automatically on each update that occurs in the database.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN

[DataGridView.Refresh](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Forces the control to invalidate its client area and immediately redraw itself and any child controls.

[DataGridView.Update](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Causes the control to redraw the invalidated regions within its client area.

Since Refresh and Update just redraw your DataGridView, this won't get you too far, if you *don't have* any cyclic checking on your DataSource (f.e. your database).